# Jmeter Testing Backend behaviour

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter load testing. I am doing tests for a web based application. Will the load testing actions can be seen from the DB BE? for ex: If I am doing load testing for ordering items from amazon for 100 threads, can I see the load from Back end like 100 people ordered from amazon is recorded in DB?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is a tool to manage interactions with services, e.g. manage HTTP requests. It does not affect how your services will deal with the interactions.

So, to answer if your interactions will change the state of a DB, then: Not necessarily.

It will depend on what service you are hitting.

You may have a service that is running locally configured to use a stubbed DB, returning always some specific value. You may have a repository in the file system. You may... because [databases are details](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/05/15/NODB.html).

[image]

So, if you want to see the results of your interactions in a DB, you have to hit a service that will change the DB state based on the interactions you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, JMeter provides the following test elements for working with databases:

- [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) - where you can put your database URL, credentials, etc.
- [JDBC Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) - where you can place your SQL queries to verify presence of certain entities in the database

See [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter) for example JMeter configuration for database communication.

Remember that you'll need to download the appropriate [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database and put it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) as JMeter is not shipped with any database driver libraries